# ¿Para que sirven los comentarios con 3 lineas?

Tags: c#

Existen comentarios con 3 lineas pero no logro encontrar su funcionamiento, dudo que sea un simple comentario ya que al utilizar tres lineas el comentario se oscurece pero al agregar dos, cuatro lineas o mas vuelve a su color original en la cual me a llamado la atención incluso al hacer escribir

```
///<
```

me aparecen otros tipos de opciones en la cual mas aumenta mi curiosidad para que servirá

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Primero comenzemos con los tipos de comentarios que se pueden emplear en C#

Tenemos 3 tipos:

A)) *Comentarios de una linea: **//***

**Ejemplo:**

```
//comentario
int a = 1; //otro comentario
```

B)) *Comentario de varias lineas: `/* */`*

**Ejemplo:**

```
/* comentario
* de varias
* líneas */
```

C)) *Comentario de plantilla de documentacion: `///`*

Esos tres slashes `///` se usan para crear una plantilla de un comentario de documentación, la cual luego puede **generar documentacion automaticamente**, es util para:

1) **Mostrar informes XML.**

2) Dar ayudas al autocompletar el nombre o parámetros de la clase, objeto, variable, etc

3) Generar la propia documentación del programa basada exclusivamente en estos comentarios.

```
///<summary>
///summary description
///</summary>
///<remarks>
///This is a test.
///</remarks>
```

Es decir que con esa etiqueta **///** todo los comentarios que agregues y les añadas las correspondientes etiquetas generaran un **XML** con un formato de documentado.

*En otras palabras es como hacer un codigo HTML pero con las especificaciones del codigo, como variables, objetos, clases, las cuales tendran un formato especifico dentro del XML*

**Ejemplos:**

**Documentar clases**

```
///<summary>
///Clase principal de la aplicación.
///</summary>
///<remarks>
///Lee archivos de configuración y crea los hilos que ejecutan el resto del programa.
///</remarks>
class CApp {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        ...
    }
}
```

*Entre las etiquetas `<summary>` y `</summary>` ponemos la descripción o resumen de la clase. Las etiquetas `<remarks>` y `</remarks>` las usamos para comentarios especiales, no se verán en el autocompletado pero sí en la documentación.*

**Documentar miembros**

```
class CApp2 {
    ///<summary>
    ///Variable que almacena el número de reintentos al acceder a un archivo.
    ///</summary>
    ///<remarks>
    ///Puede ser modificada en cualquier momento.
    ///</remarks>
    int var = 1;
    ...
}
```

**Documentar métodos/funciones**

```
///<summary>
///Lee la configuración de la aplicación desde el disco.
///</summary>
///<return>
///Devuelve true si la configuración fue leida. Si hubo algún error se devuelve false.
///</return>
///<param name="archivo">
///Ruta del archivo en disco a leer.
///</param>
public bool LeeConfig(string archivo) {
    bool c = false;
    ...
    return c;
}
```

Entre las etiquetas `<return>` y `</return>` se explica el valor devuelto por la función, y las etiquetas `<param></param>` se utilizan para describir cada uno de los parámetros del método/función.
Generar documentación

```
A parte de las ayudas al autocompletado que aparecen automaticamente en Visual Studio, SharpDevelop y MonoDevelop al documentar el código, también se pueden generar archivos de documentación.
```

**En Windows, usando la implementación del .NET Framework hecha por Microsoft, se utiliza el siguiente comando:**

```
C:\>csc /doc:Documentacion.xml Programa.cs
```

**Con esto podras generar tu documentacion del sistema en formato XML**

**Ejemplo:**

**CODIGO C#:**

```
 // compile with: /doc:DocFileName.xml 

    /// text for class TestClass
    public class TestClass
    {
        /// <summary>DoWork is a method in the TestClass class.
        /// <para>Here's how you could make a second paragraph in a description. <see cref="System.Console.WriteLine(System.String)"/> for information about output statements.</para>
        /// <seealso cref="TestClass.Main"/>
        /// </summary>
        public static void DoWork(int Int1)
        {
        }

        /// text for Main
        static void Main()
        {
        }
```

**Generara este XML:**

```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>  
<doc>  
    <assembly>  
        <name>YourNamespace</name>  
    </assembly>  
    <members>  
        <member name="T:DotNetEvents.TestClass">  
            text for class TestClass  
        </member>  
        <member name="M:DotNetEvents.TestClass.DoWork(System.Int32)">  
            <summary>DoWork is a method in the TestClass class.  
            <para>Here's how you could make a second paragraph in a description. <see cref="M:System.Console.WriteLine(System.String)"/> for information about output statements.</para>  
            <seealso cref="M:DotNetEvents.TestClass.Main"/>  
            </summary>  
        </member>  
        <member name="M:DotNetEvents.TestClass.Main">  
            text for Main  
        </member>  
    </members>  
</doc>
```

Si te interesa mas sobre los INFORMES DE CODIGO:

*Citando a **https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-ve/library/aa291781(v=vs.71).aspx***

**Crear informes de código**

**Visual Studio .NET 2003**

> Una vez definidos los objetos y las interfaces de un proyecto, puede
>   ver la estructura de dichos objetos e interfaces, así como la
>   estructura de los miembros, mediante informes Web de comentario de
>   código. Estos informes muestran información sobre las definiciones del
>   código en una serie de páginas .htm. Si utiliza C# u otros lenguajes
>   que admiten comentarios de documentación XML, puede utilizar estos
>   comentarios para ofrecer descripciones resumidas, comentarios de la
>   forma en que se comporta una definición o resúmenes de parámetros para
>   funciones.
>
> Nota   Visual C++ proporciona compatibilidad limitada para comentarios
>   de documentación XML. Los informes Web de comentarios de código
>   reconocen las siguientes etiquetas XML:

`<summary></summary>`   Describe un miembro para un tipo.

`<remarks></remarks>`   Especifica información general de una clase u otro tipo.

`<param></param>`   Se utiliza en el comentario de una declaración de método para describir uno de los parámetros del método.

`<returns></returns>`   Se utiliza en el comentario de una declaración de método para describir el valor devuelto.

`<newpara></newpara>`   Inicia un nuevo párrafo en los comentarios.

Para obtener más información de las otras etiquetas y de estas,pero en mayor profundidad: ***https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-ve/library/aa288210(v=vs.71).aspx***